# Is Morocco Safe for Tourists?

Tags: morocco

We are planning our summer holiday and Morocco seems good value.

I have read conflicting reports about the country though, some reports suggest it is not safe to leave your hotel complex.  I am especially concerned as we have 3 teenage girls who are all blonde and this seems to attract unwanted attention in some places!

We are a white British family, never been to Morocco and would be looking for a package deal to a hotel.

Comment: "Safe" means different things to different people, and experiences will vary widely depending on what kind of trip you are planning. (And there is hardly a shortage of unwanted attention given to young women in any part of the world.) I'm afraid all this question will invite are anecdotes and opinions and political debate. Please see *[Asking a good safety question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3314)* and *[Personal safety](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1906)* for some ways you might [edit] it for greater focus.

Comment: It is relative question. Is England safe for tourist?

Answer (score 22):

Yes you will attract unwanted attentions.

It is safe, as long as you follow good old common sense.
(among others)

1. Keep valuable at home or in your hotel room (for example, you don't need you gold watch)
2. Keep an eye on your belongings (watch for pickpockets)
3. Be mindful of scams, be and stay polite and just walk away if feeling uneasy.
4. Dress and behave conservatively. (follow local customs)
5. Follow local customs, laws and regulations.

If you keep to the big cities, Fes, Marrakesh ,Rabat and Casablanca you should be OK.

If not feeling more "adventurous" I'd get a local guide (recommended by your hotel) when doing some sightseeings.

I could point that to you to (remember concerning terrorism, there are unfortunately no safe places anywhere anymore):

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/morocco

or to for some tips

https://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/safety-in-morocco/

Comment: Regarding "Dress and behave conservatively": if you're a big city, you can pretty much dress and act like you would in Europe. Nobody's going to mind. The only exception would be alcohol and the likes during the month of Ramadan (but then this falls under "follow local laws").

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Would it affect getting unwanted attention though?

Comment: @gerrit Whenever I go to Morocco with my family my sister (unfortunately) receives unwanted attention however she's dressed. It never goes beyond whistling or lewd comments, though.

Comment: Not any recommendation about women going around alone? The man are more respected in their culture.

Comment: "If you keep to the big cities ... you should be OK." But you will also get more unpleasant unwanted attention (in my experience).

Comment: "unwanted attention" , I live in Canada and some women draw my attention !. Anyway, I'm originally from Morocco and I have never head a tourist get assaulted. to be stolen his things, it exists everywhere in the world, so be careful as you do in your country, that's all

Answer (score 12):

Safety is relative to the individual. I, being from South Africa, consider myself to have a high tolerance for risk. I would consider Morocco a safe country - but my tolerance could be different to you and your family. Crime is relatively rare for most tourists if you take the correct precautions and closely watch your possessions.

Since you are British, you should / could follow the advice of your country. https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/morocco/safety-and-security

Also, read the Stay Safe section on this page. https://wikitravel.org/en/Morocco

Answer (score 11):

I and my boyfriend (I more or less blond) have done a 3 week bicycle trip in Morocco 1 year ago: we were traveling alone also in quite remote and very non-touristic areas (Atlas and Anti-Atlas Mountains) and sleeping "wild" in a tent.

Our impression is the following: in the more non-touristic areas the people are nicer and we felt more safe. The people were happy to see some "foreign faces" but were not intrusive. Children asked sometimes for some sweets. In very touristic cities (like Marrakesh) the people are sometimes very intrusive and desperately want to sell you something, and the cities are horribly crowded. None the less nobody was really aggressive toward us.

I would definitely recommend a vacation in Morocco (the country is very beautiful), but maybe not in the most touristic cities (but avoid west Sahara because of politic situation, border areas to other countries and Rif Mountains). Also outside you can find some nice hotels but you can then more enjoy the time and the nature without being "attack" all the time to buy something. The probability of robbery is also then smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I visited Morocco together with my blonde girlfriend last summer. Experiences where mixed. We've been to Cassablanca, Marakkesh, Essaouira and ended up in Taghazout for a week of surfing. In general, everything was ok and nothing happened. People had warned us about Marrakesh so we where ready to fend street merchants off. We both had the feeling that it wasn't as bad as people told us. Yes they asked you to buy stuff a lot, but if you told them no, they left. I definitely have had worse experiences on this front. However, you will hardly see any women on the street on a general day. This can sometimes come across as intimidating. For us this was especially true at the Gnawa festival in Essaouira where we left because middle aged men kept touching my girlfriend's bum. Not a great experience. Apart from that it was a good holiday. Especially in Taghazout where, mainly because of the surf culture, people are way more relaxed towards tourists. But also the rest. Marrakesh really looks like a city from a fairy tale. One last thing. This is one of those countries where you need to be careful with the food.